# google app engine datastore update error django python

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

i want to update an existing entity in google app engine datastore.
i know that put() either create/update entry. but in my case it will always create a new entry why?...

### my edit function in views.py

```
def edit(request,mykey):
   employee=Employeeprofile.get(mykey)
   data={
     'employee_name':employee.employee_name, 
     'employee_number': employee.employee_number,
     'employee_email': employee.employee_email,
     'employee_mobilenumber':employee.employee_mobilenumber,
     'employee_address': employee.employee_address
   }

   form= Employeeprofileform(data)
   import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
   if request.POST:
       form= Employeeprofileform(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():          
               employee.employee_name =form.cleaned_data['employee_name']
               employee.employee_number=form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
               employee.employee_email = form.cleaned_data['employee_email']
               employee.employee_mobilenumber= form.cleaned_data['employee_mobilenumber']
               employee.employee_address = form.cleaned_data['employee_address']
               employee.put(mykey)
               return HttpResponseRedirect("/listallemployees/")
            else:
               return render_to_response('main/edit.html', {'form': form,'mykey':mykey})

      else:
    return render_to_response('main/edit.html', {'form': form,'mykey':mykey})
```

why?...

i need to update the data with same key.
iam using django1.2

Comment: Are the values of `mykey` actual keys to existing entries? Can you share the code for `Employeeprofile.get`?

Comment: sorry i didn't get u... keys are fine ....     in my template <a href="/employee/user/edit/{{ employee.key}}/" >edit</a>   </t></li>   this is the edit link...